# Console application can't connect to sql server instance from server, but can from local machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, console-application

I have a few asp.net web applications running on a dedicated server.. For one of the websites, I am doing a maintenance task of upgrading all user uploaded images to new naming convention.

I wrote a small, simple console application to do that job. I put the connection string in my app.config like so:

```
<add key="CS" value="Data Source=1.1.1.1;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=usr; Password=pwd" />
```

<sup>Of course, the details here are dummy they are not actually `MyDatabase` etc... but I do connect to the sql server using an IP address</sup>

All my web applications have same format, same details in their `web.config` files, with the exception of just the database name. Everything works fine too.

I can run the console application from my local dev machine, with the production database, and it connects fine, no problem.  (ran a test query on a test DB successfully)

Now, I need to access the hard disk to rename files etc... so I want to run this console application on the server.. I FTP the app to my server and try to run it there.. it errors out saying:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured 
to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces,
error : 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Like I mentioned earlier, same connection is running fine from my dev machine, this only happens when I try to run the console application in the server..

I've tried searching but couldn't find a similar case anywhere..  esp. as all my web applications that use the same value works fine.. do I need to tell the application to use something?

Many thanks

Comment: @SLaks, hi, could you expand that a little, what do I need to check in the firewall, please?

Comment: try putting an internal IP or machine name instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the web server and DB server on the same machine?

Regardless, on the web server open a command prompt and do the following:

```
telnet <ip>, 1433
```

This assumes your running your SQL Server on the standard port, change accordingly if not.

See if you can connect to the DB Server via telnet, helps figure out if there are firewall/basic connection issues.

Comment: Hi, telnet is not recognized, I tried to add the feature, but got the message that a restart is pending and no features can be added while a restart is pending.. and I don't really want to restart the prod server right now! Also, the database is local, but the IP starts with 192.x.x.x .. I assume that's also local?

Comment: probably a good idea, to not restart! It depends on what you mean by the same, 'localhost' technically resolves to the IP 127.0.0.1. Try putting the in 192.x.x.x,p where p is the SQL Server port number and see if you can connect. Include the comma between the two!

Comment: Hi, tried the port number.. didn;t make any changes.. now I wonder, if the changes are taking place at all, I'll try to pring the connection string on console and inspect that..

Comment: download the free telnet client 'Putty', it doesn't require any install. Extract and run. You can then test telneting to the IP and port and ensure you have access. Have you configured SQL Server to listen for IP connections on a certain IP address or does it accept any ip?

Comment: hm, I feel like an idiot now.. I was updating the app.settings but somehow the console didn't buy into the update.. I have a dependency dll, so instead of updating all of the files, I just updated the exe file.. and the exe somehow had the app.config from my local machine.. once I updated all dlls it works fine now.. if I make a small change in my console app, do I have to update all the dll and dependency files along with the exe to the server?

Comment: HI, I'm going to accept your answer as you eventually helped me figure out the problem.. thanks for your patience!

Comment: When you udpate app.settings, they are reflected into your app.config. However, you then need to rebuild to create the appname.exe.config file as this is what the console looks for at runtime. When working with multi project solutions, doing a 'Clean' and 'Build' is best.

Comment: Aah! I see.. didn't know that about the exe.config file.. 

thank you!