# Problems with SQL Server connection in console app

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, model-view-controller

- The SQL server is located on a remote machine.
- I can connect to it with MVC app.
- I can connect to it with SSMS.
- But I can not do it in console app.

Neither entity nor SqlConnection is working. 
Connection string is the same as in console and mvc app (which works). What can it be? Any ideas?

Error I am getting

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

What can it be?

```
<add name="DBContext" connectionString="data source=serverip;initial catalog=catalogue;user id=user;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
cn.ConnectionString = "data source=serverip;initial catalog=catalogue;user id=user;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient";
cn.Open();
Console.WriteLine(cn.State.ToString());
```

The problem is that console app uses 445 and 139 port. In terms of security. But why MVC app doesn't use it. And how I can I use it without opening this port. Even dividing db part in different library didn't work.

Comment: Please share codes that you use for connection as well.

Comment: Please share ConnectionString

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console application can't connect to sql server instance from server, but can from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031112/console-application-cant-connect-to-sql-server-instance-from-server-but-can-fr)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031112/console-application-cant-connect-to-sql-server-instance-from-server-but-can-fr

Comment: I'm assuming the connection string data is masked, and you're not actually attempting to connect to a server located on `serverip`... Make sure you've got the address correct, and the firewall isn't blocking the 1433 port on the client computer.

Comment: Sure it is masked. There is ip. 172.20.256.256. The problem is that connection goes from 445 port and 139, not 1433. How can i fix it?

Comment: It doesn't matter what port your app is hosted on, that has no bearing on what port it tries to hit on the SQL Server. It will hit port 1433 unless you've configured your connection not to.

Comment: 172.20.256.256 isn't a valid IP, because the 256 segments are out of range. Are you just masking it so you don't share the real IP with us? Using SSMS, are you able to connect to the actual IP with the username and password from your connection string?

Comment: Of course it isn't. I won't put here the real ip